# How to use the thousands comma separator while be able to convert that number to a normal float or int?

Tags: python-3.x

I create a PyQt calculator, and I want to implement the comma separator, while still being able to convert the label text to a float.

some code:

```
class CalculatorWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Calculator):
    def __init__(self):
        #other code
        self.pushButton_digitnumber.clicked.connect(self.digit_pressed)

    def digit_pressed(self):
        button = self.sender()

        newLabel = format(float(self.operation_screen.text() + button.text()), '.15g')

        self.operation_screen.setText(newLabel)
```

If I do `format(float(self.operation_screen.text() + button.text()), ',.15g')`, the program crashes because it can't convert the text to a float because of the commas. If this problem has a solution, please help me ! Thanks!

Comment: `.replace(',', '.')`?

Comment: this is not working :((

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete and variable example than. And/or provide the full error traceback.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse what is not clear in my explanation ?

Comment: It is more an issue of it not being verifiable. We cannot run your code to debug it ourselves which means it is both not complete nor verifiable. Remove the parts with `PyQt` and make it so acts the same with just normal python (i.e. no external modules) than update your question. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://github.com/Kirusha05/PyQt5-Calculator , this is the source code, all the logical operations are stored in calculator.py, and you run the program from main.py   . It is not finished, but I hope this will help you to debug the code and maybe solve my question.

Comment: You should make it Minimul....

Comment: This is the minimal version https://github.com/Kirusha05/MinimalCalculator/blob/master/QPushButton.py . It is about 50 lines of code

Comment: Now pleeeaaasseee help me !